# Aligning two divs the right of one div

Tags: css

In the following example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmaoxepf/) , I need to align `menu` and `categories` divs to the right of the logo div and I need them to stay one under another as they are right now, but I just cannot get it displaed as needed.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: try to use float: right  with width it will help

Comment: You can wrap the `categories` and `menu`, and float both `logo` and the wrapper left..(https://jsfiddle.net/pmaoxepf/2/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `menu` and `category` in a div and float that new div.

HTML

```
<div id="header">
<div class="verticalcenter relative">
<div id="logo">logo</div>
<div class="wrap" align="left">
<div id="menu">menu</div>
<div id="categories">categories</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header{
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 100%;
}
.verticalcenter{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo{
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width: 220px;
}

#menu{
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.wrap {
    float:right;
    width:75%;
}
```

NOTE: I added a width to the wrapper div so it sits next to your logo, rather than to the far right of the area. You can drop the width if that's the behaviour you would prefer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="verticalcenter relative">
<div id="logo">logo</div>
<section>
<div id="menu" class="right-div">menu</div>
<div id="categories" class="right-div">categories</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS below :

```
#header{
background: white;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
z-index: 50;
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.verticalcenter{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo{
width: 25%;
height: 150px;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
vertical-align: top;
min-width: 220px;
float: left;
}

section{
float: left;
width: 75%;
}

#menu{
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.right-div{
box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
height: 70px;
}
```